# Displaying entities data with EditorForModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I've got data filled enumerator which I send to the view, I render the EditorForModel like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<TestProj.Models.Hours>
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

than in the EditorTemplates.Hours.cshtml:

```
@model TestProj.Models.Hours
<div>
@Html.CheckBoxFor(
    x => x.Selected, 
    new { 
        @class = "jcf-unselectable",
        id = HtmlHelper.GenerateIdFromName("cb_slice." + ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(""))
    }
)
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.SliceName)
</div>
```

When the page is rendered I want to show all the the SliceNames data , Not the entity's name "SliceName" for the labels display.

So it will render the checkbox along with the label with the data behind SliceName.

I'm trying this option since I've understood using viewbags with loops ain't recommended, However I'd like suggestion behind the EditorForModel scope as well.

EDIT:
If I use :

```
@Html.DisplayTextFor(x => x.SliceName)
```

-Ill get the data behind SliceName (Text only).

If I Use :

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.SliceName)
```

-Ill get the title "SliceName" for the label's text.

How do I use  @Html.LabelFor to get the data as text like @Html.DisplayTextFor?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have a problem with your Form.

If you do:

```
@Html.BeginForm()
{
...
}
```

instead of this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
...
}
```

The names of your Model will appear instead of the values of the Model.

Comment: In my layout I'm rendering the body at some point " @RenderBody()" which will render the area with EditorForModel at the main area of the page, I didn't even have @Html.BeginForm() or @using(Html.BeginForm()) , I've tried placing it in my body page like this(only required part for this example): 
       @using(Html.BeginForm("Search_Times", "Search"))
{
@model IEnumerable<TestProj.Models.Hours>
@Html.EditorForModel()
}

Still rendering the titles and not the data.

Comment: @Html.DisplayTextFor(x => x.SliceName) for example, Will show the data behind "SliceName" , however it's not a "Label" and cannot take more arguments to format the element.

Comment: I think I understand your question now. @Html.LabelFor won't work because it is for displaying labels.  Have you tried @Html.DisplayFor()?

Comment: The object must be rendered as a label to match the css given to me as part of the project's guidelines.

Comment: Basically @Html.LabelFor() won't do what you need so you'll need to find an alternative.  Luckily I think there will be some easy work arounds.  What does the HTML need to look like when it's rendered?